# How to port cocos2d v2.1 ios game to Android using Apportable

Tags: android, ios, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder, apportable

I'm using cocos2d v2.1 and Apportable now supports only cocos2d latest version or version greater than 3. Apportable Sprite Builder Android Plugin not support cocos2d v2.1. [Sprite Builder Android Plugin](https://store.spritebuilder.com/products/spritebuilder-android-plugin-starter)
In every tutorial that I found they says download the sdk and run apportable load etc. My question is from where I can find the sdk which support cocos2d v2.1 as I didn't find any link of older sdk to download.
Please Help.

Comment: You should ask this on the SpriteBuilder forum if you haven't already: http://forum.spritebuilder.com  On SO, asking for recommendations or finding links is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Apportable no longer makes available the general emulation SDK that was used pre-Sprite Builder, they've pivoted to supporting SpriteBuilder only. Besides, if you want your game to run well on Android, you really do want to update to Cocos2D v3.

Comment: No, Apportable do support older versions what you have to do is to make a request to apportable sdk team via email sdk@apportable.com and they will provide you a download link.

Comment: Pfft. I'd been told they didn't and believed it without checking. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just received answer from support.

> Our primary game product is the SpriteBuilder IDE, which supports
>   versions of Cocos2D 3.2+. If you can upgrade your game to a newer
>   version of Cocos2D that is what I would recommend. Otherwise, our old
>   SDK is still available for games built on older versions of Cocos2D.
>   It looks like you are already set up to use the SDK. We are no longer
>   actively supporting it but there is a large community at
>   forum.apportable.com that can help you if you choose that direction.